# Why is dangerouslySetInnerHTML property returning Uncaught Invariant Violation error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, markdown

I am trying to build a simple markdown previewer using react and marked.js. Feel like I am almost there - I can console.log the markdown, but for some reason I get an error when trying to insert the HTML. Here is the code:

```
//import { useState } from 'react';
const {useState} = React

//MAIN APP
function App(){
  const [text, setText]=useState("Test")

  function editorHandler(event){
    setText(event.target.value)
  }


  return( 
  <div>
      <h1> MARKDOWN PREVIEWER </h1>
      <Editor onChange={editorHandler} markDown={text}/>
      <Preview previewText={text}/>
  </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("App"))


// EDITOR COMPONENT
function Editor(props){
  return(
  <div className="window">
    <h2>editor</h2>
    <textarea id="editor" value={props.markDown} onChange={props.onChange} placeHolder="Write something here"> </textarea>
  </div>
  )
}

// PREVIEW COMPONENT
function Preview(props){


 console.log(marked(props.previewText))  // works, outputs: <p>Test</p>

  function getMarkDownText() {
    const rawMarkup = marked(props.previewText)
    return {__html: rawMarkup};
  } 

  return(
  <div className="window">
      <h2>previewer</h2>
      <div id="preview" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={getMarkDownText()}> </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

The problem seems to be with that last div (id preview). I get the following error message which is not very helpful: "Uncaught Invariant Violation: Minified React error #60"

Codepen is here if easier: https://codepen.io/rpollock03/pen/RwWvYQb?editors=1011

Grateful for an explanation of what I'm doing wrong. I am learning React so apologies if this is something silly! I've tried reading the docs - the marked.js ones weren't very clear in my opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
 <div id="preview" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={getMarkDownText()}> </div>
```

with

```
 <div id="preview" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={getMarkDownText()} />
```

This will solve it.

Codepen uses minified react-dom (react-dom.production.min.js). Hence you are not clearly seeing the error. In the minified production build of React, they avoid sending down full error messages in order to reduce the number of bytes sent over the wire.

But if you open browser console, you will find the following message

> Invariant Violation: Minified React error #60; visit
>   https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=60 for the full
>   message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and
>   additional helpful warnings.

And once you go to the link in above message, you will get actual error, which is

> Can only set one of `children` or `props.dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

As children are not allowed (and also not required) when dangerouslySetInnerHTML is used, to solve this issue, we removed the children by replacing `<div> </div>` with `<div/>`

Comment: Thank you so much, this solved the error. Such a simple thing and it makes total sense!